# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of

Tags: php, joomla

I am not a programmer at all, but I need to get an OLD Joomla site up and running long enough for me to scrape the content out of the site (articles and navigation headings) and start a new WordPress site. Currently, the site (www.muellerfamilylaw.com) shows the following error:

> jtablesession::Store Failed
>   DB function failed with error number 145
>   Table './tempmu5_muellerfamilylaw/jos_session' is marked as crashed and should be repaired SQL=INSERT INTO `jos_session` ( `session_id`,`time`,`username`,`gid`,`guest`,`client_id` ) VALUES ( '7f0d46db0c41fddae0302015fc529d2e','1491314393','','0','1','0' )

If anyone can help me repair this enough to just get the old site up long enough for me to gleen all the page content, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I would backup the table (if it lets you, or just copy the raw files on the server) and recreate it with the same structure and try again. No guarantee but might get you somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `phpMyAdmin` and issue the following query:

```
REPAIR TABLE jos_session
```

If it doesn't work, then just drop the table and recreate it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jos_session` (
  `session_id` varchar(191) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `client_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `guest` tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT 1,
  `time` varchar(14) DEFAULT '',
  `data` mediumtext,
  `userid` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `username` varchar(150) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 DEFAULT COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

By the way, the reason this happened is because you are likely using MyISAM instead of InnoDB - it is a good idea to switch to InnoDB as InnoDB tables are less likely to crash. We have posted about this very issue [here](http://www.itoctopus.com/your-joomla-website-is-crashing-constantly-switch-from-myisam-to-innodb).

Answer (score 0):

For your table crashed issue, you should look into fixing tables with `repair table` command in MYSQL or mysqlcheck.

For the memory exhaustion issue, since this is a temporary thing, using php's `ini_set` function as follows should suffice.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2G'); // adjust the 2G as required.
```

You would need to place this somewhere before line 117 where your exhaustion is happening.